# today's date filter showing next day data in table chart

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

When i select date as sept 16,i get to see sept 16 6am and sept 17 data until 5:59 AM.
It is treating 24 hours from sept 16 am to sept 17 6am.
Is there any issue with date field or report filter issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery's date functions work based on UTC timezone.
The UI you are using probably converts them into your local timezone, and you are seeing the 6 hours difference.

Comment: Is the screenshot you shared from Tableau?

Comment: According to [this](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6401549?hl=en) Data Studio uses UTC standard time, but if your data set does not use UTC you can use the [TODATE function](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300) to convert the date field to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

For visibility purposes I am posting [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57986698/todays-date-filter-showing-next-day-data-in-table-chart#comment102397244_57987003) as an answer:

As @Pentium10 mentioned:

> BigQuery's date functions work based on UTC timezone. The UI you are using probably converts them into your local timezone, and you are seeing the 6 hours difference.

According to [this](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6401549?hl=en) Data Studio uses UTC standard time, but if your data set does not use UTC you can use the [TODATE function](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300) to convert the date field to UTC.